# Hide / Show component in react native

Tags: react-native

I want to show  when I onPress custom components.
A custom component is a  wrapped in multiple  and .

I mean that  show when  onPress
Of course,  is wrapped in .

Like this,

```
 import React from 'react';
 import {
   SafeAreaView,
   Text,
   FlatList,
   View,
   StyleSheet,
   StatusBar,
   Image,
   ScrollView,
   TouchableHighlight,
   TouchableOpacity,
   Button,
 } from 'react-native';

import HeartButtons from './buttons';
import Item from './items';

const App = () => {

  const renderItem = ({item}: any) => (
    <View style={{backgroundColor: colors.white}}>
     <Item title={item.title} />
     <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.5} style={styles.buttonHeartStyle}>
       <Image source={heart} />
     </TouchableOpacity>
     <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.5} style={styles.buttonCheckStyle}>
       <Image source={check} />
     </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );

 return (
  <SafeAreaView>
  <FlatList
    data={DATA}
    renderItem={renderItem}
    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
  />
  <TouchableOpacity
    activeOpacity={0.7}
    onPress={clickHandler}
    style={styles.touchableOpacityStyle}>
  </TouchableOpacity>
</SafeAreaView>
  );
    
};
export default App;
```

It's part of the code.
When I clicked `<Item title={item.title} />` ,
 in the renderItem function should be shown.

What should I do?

I haven't had it in a week.
I'd appreciate it if you could help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you are trying to achieve. Could you please share some drawings/screenshots and some more explanation? Are you trying to delete rows from the list?

Comment: Have you defined your "clickHandler"? If you have not, you should implement it first. If you have, you should include it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Just modify your `renderItem` to this

```
const renderItem = ({ item }: any) => {
  const [isActive, setActive] = useState(false);
  return (
    <View style={{ backgroundColor: colors.white }}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setActive(!isActive)}>
        <Item title={item.title} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
      {
        isActive && 
        <>
        // Add here what you want to show
        </>
      }
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: If you write according to the code above, an error occurs. 
Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance. 
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method. 

But isn't it `const [isActive, setActive] = useState(false)` , 
not `const [isActive, setActive] = useState[false]` ?
You're supposed to use square brackets, not square brackets.

But if you write the code like this, you get an error.
Minified React error #321; 
I feel like I'm in a swamp of error.

Comment: Sorry I used the wrong syntax, this is the right way `const [isActive, setActive] = useState(false)`. I have modified my code.